# select a partir de data no banco postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Como faço um select no banco postgreSQL pra ele me retorna os dados  a partir de uma data especifica, por exemplo tenho um campo do tipo timestamp com nome data_entrevista, quero que ele me traz os dados cadastrados desde o dia de hoje para frente.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela Where data_entrevista = data de hoje para frente
```

Comment: na verdade, o termo certo não seria **"do dia de hoje"**, e sim **"de um dia específico"**. O Hoje sempre vai acontecer, esquecendo as datas anteriores (isso dizendo, por poder usar o `now()`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize `>=` para trazer apenas datas mais recentes:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela Where data_entrevista >= '2016-10-19 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 4):

Como o campo é timestamp (data e horário) pode fazer um cast (`::tipo`) para `date` e fazer a comparação apenas com a  data atual `CURRENT_DATE`

```
SELECT * FROM tabela Where data_entrevista::date >= CURRENT_DATE
```

[Postgres - documentação - Datetime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score -2):

Assim:

SELECT * FROM tabela Where data_entrevista::date = '2019-10-16'